# how to send data from ajax to backend express

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I want to send the data from frontend to backend nodejs using nodejs, how do i do that?

here is my ajax code

```
const news = document.getElementById("news");
news.addEventListener('click',(e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    let data = " ";
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?category=technology&apiKey=<api_key>';

        xhttp.open('GET',url, true);
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(this.status === 200 && this.readyState === 4){
                let data = JSON.parse(this.response);
            }
        }

        xhttp.send();

})
```

and the backend code is

```
const newsController = () => {
    return{
        getNews(req, res){
          console.log(res)
        },
        

    }
}

module.exports = newsController;
```

the data should be send to backend on get route so that I can render the data on html page.

Comment: `the data should be send to backend on get route so that I can render the data on html page.` why don’t you generate the page directly in the browser or why don’t you request the data on the server. Requesting in the client and sending it to the server to generate the html page does not make much sens.

Answer (score 0):

You can trying this code, but layers userService and userRepo I'm removing from this example, they're excessive.

App.js

```
import express from "express";
import { userRouter } from "./routes/userRoutes.js";

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api', userRouter);

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`http://localhost:${PORT}`));
```

userRoutes.js

```
import userController from "../controller/userController.js";
import { Router } from "express";
const router = new Router();

router.get('/users', userController.getUsers.bind(userController));

export {router as userRouter}
```

userController.js

```
import userService from "../service/userService.js";

class UserController {

    constructor(userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
           
    async getUsers(req, res) {
        res.json(await this.userService.getUsers());
    }

}

export default new UserController(userService);
```

Or you may using from official documentation express.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).